# USB boot into Win 10 causes disk checks next boot from SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, usb-boot

### Hardware Involved

- HP Zbook G2
- 500gb Samsung SSD (C:) - Windows 7 boot (For Work)
- 1TB Hitachi HDD (D:) - Data Storage
- SanDisk Extreme Go USB 3.1 - Windows 10 LTSB boot (For Personal)

### Problem

1. Boot PC into Windows 10 from USB. Works great. Shutdown when done.
2. When I go to boot into Windows 7 from SSD, the OS always tells me that I have to run a disk check on both my C: and D: drives. This takes awhile on the D: so it gets annoying.
3. I don't have a picture, but it does say that it is correcting issues. It's the same thing every time but I forgot what it said it was fixing. If you think it would be helpful I can add it to this post afterwards next time I go through this.
4. It only ever tells me to do a disk check after I have booted from the USB. And after the checks are complete everything runs great.

Does anyone know why this happens? And better yet, would you know how to fix it? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start then Run , type cmd and press Enter . Next type **fsutil dirty query x:** where x: is your boot drive. This queries the drive, and more than likely it will tell you that it is dirty.

Next, type **chkntfs /x c:** . The X tells Windows to NOT check that particular drive on the next reboot. Now manually reboot your computer, it should not do a chkdsk and should take you directly to normal Windows login.

Once Windows has fully loaded, bring up another Command Prompt and enter **chkdsk c: /r** . Reply Y when asked if you want this to happen on the next boot. This should take you through 5 stages of the chkdsk scan and will unset that dirty bit. This can take an hour or more depending on the size of your hard drive, be patient and let it complete.

Once booted back to Windows, open another Command Prompt and query the dirty bit again by entering **fsutil dirty query c:** and Windows will confirm that the dirty bit is not set on that drive.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly! Can I ask you why this worked & why the previous times chkdisk ran automatically it didn't reset the dirty bit?

Comment: I guess I should've rebooted into each system a few times before I said it worked. My D: drive is now dirty after switching twice.